# Why are answers just not getting accepted

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

As least from what I have personally seen, on most sites where there are good answers given to questions, many of those answers are accepted. If you post the best answer, it is accepted like 75% of the time. On some sites like Space Exploration or Stack Overflow, probably 90%. And yet out of 329 questions, only 105 have accepted an answer. We have a 95% answered rate, so that is not the problem. And we have a 2.6 answer ratio, meaning that one should be bound to be helpful. Only 19 questions are closed, and all but 5 of the closed questions still have answers. 99% of our answers are positvely scored, 96% are scored 1 or more, 82% are scored 2 or more, 35% are scored 5 or more, and 5% are scored 10 or more. This mean that plenty of questions get quality answers with a bunch to pick from. So why does hardly anything get accepted?

Comment: Related question. Does it matter for questions that legitimately have multiple answers? and if so why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One reason I have left some of my questions without an accepted answer is because those questions ask about a range of possible approaches or considerations; they have received good (objective) answers which cover one or two approaches or considerations, but I think there is plenty to be covered by other answers. Marking those questions as "accepted" could make people think no more answers are needed or wanted, when the opposite is true.

Still, if no more answers get written for a few days, I try to come back later to mark a good answer as accepted. So most of my questions now have an accepted answer even though I left them without one for a while. Of the few that remain, one is self-answered by me but I think my answer is too narrow to fully address the question, and another has several good answers which are hard to choose between.

Comment: Do you think other agree with you?

Comment: @Starship-OnStrike I don't know, I haven't asked them, so I can only speak for myself.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess votes will tell

Answer (score 2):

I have two theories, but of course we cannot know the real answer without asking a large number of askers:

#### Culture

A lot of our askers have extensive history on Code Golf, where [it is normal not to accept an answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8363/43319).

#### Subjectivity

The nature of many questions here is such that answers must be subjective. If there's no objectively real answer, it doesn't make so much sense to accept one answer as the definitive one.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146616/discussion-on-answer-by-adam-why-are-answers-just-not-getting-accepted); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.